# Is the following language is a context free grammar language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

[image]

The question is to determine whether L is a context free grammar language, what do you think?

Comment: Probably best to intersect $L$ with the regular language $0^*1^* \# 0^*1^*$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the word $w = 0^n1^n0^n \# 0^n1^n0^n \in L$ for a sufficiently large value of $n$.

By the pumping lemma for context-free languages, we know that if $L$ is context-free then there are$a,b,c,d,e = \Sigma^*$, with $|bcd| < n$ and $|bd|>1$ such that $w=abcde$ and, for every $i \ge 0$, $a b^i c d^i e\in L$.

Notice that neither $b$ nor $d$ can contain $\#$, as otherwise setting $i=0$ would show that $a c e \not\in L$.

If $c$ contains $\#$, then $b,d \in 0^*$ and $a b^i c d^i e$ is a word of the form $0^n 1^n 0^{x + i|b|}\#0^{y+i|d|} 1^n0^n$ with $x+|b|=n$ and $y+|d|=n$.  If $|b|>0$ you can make the first part of the word (before $\#$) end with more than $n$ zeros by picking $i=2$, resulting in a contradiction. Otherwise $|d|>0$ and you can make the second part of the word (after $\#$) start with less than $n$ zeros by setting $i=0$.

If $c$ does not contain $\#$ then $b$ and $c$ either both precede or both follow the unique occurrence of $\#$ in $w$. If they precede $\#$, pick $i=2$. If they follow $\#$, pick $i=0$.
In this way the first part of the word becomes longer than the second (and hence not in $L$).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but, notice that I asked if L is context free grammar and not regular.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it.

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Comment: what if x = y and |b| = |d|? Like in the case that c is exactly equals to #. It seems in that case that picking i = 2 won't work

Comment: If $x=y$ (which is the case in the words we are considering) and $|b|=|d|$ then both $b$ and $d$ are non-empty words containing only $0$s. $b$ is in the last group of $0$s of $x$ and $d$ is in the first group of $0$s of $y$. You can either choose $i=2$ (to get more trailing $0$s before the $\#$ character than at the end of the pumped word) or $i=0$ (to get fewer $0$s immediately after the $\#$ character than at the beginning of the pumped word). In any case the pumped word is not in $L$. This seems to be correctly handled in the first case of my answer as it satisfies both $|b|>0$ and $|d|>0$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CFL. We can prove this using *pumping lemma for [CFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)*.

We prove it as follows: Consider the string $s = 0^n1^n0^n\#0^n1^n0^n \in L$. By pumping lemma, for a significantly large $n$, we can split the string in five parts: $u,v,w,x,y$ such that $s = uvwxy$, $|vx| > 0$, and $uv^mwx^my \in L$ for all $m$.

Basically, you have to find out two parts of the string $s$ (at least one is non-empty), such that no matter how many times you pump it, the pumped string has to be in $L$.

It is not hard to see that no splitting satisfies the pumping lemma:

- If both $v$ and $x$ are on left side of #, then the pumped string won't stay substring of the string on right side of #.
- Work out other cases...

Comment: Thank you very much :)